# Mouse events not triggered after several clicks on element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, coffeescript, eventtrigger

I am trying to detect start/drop drags events on an element. Sometimes these events seem not to be triggered. The source is on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jiewmeng/r8Phv/)**. Try holding down mouse in the orange bar and dragging to create intervals (in blue). In Chrome, try do this for 3 times. On the 3rd time, I notice nearly always, the mouseup event is not triggered, making the effect weird. Even when the mouse is not pressed, the drag event is still triggered

[Video on Screenr](http://screenr.com/LugH)

```
$ ->
    isMouseDown = false
    isDragging = false
    $draggedInterval = undefined
    $test = $("#test")
    $test
        # code related to attaching handlers to trigger custom events
        .on "mousedown", ->
            isMouseDown = true
        .on "mouseup", (evt) -> 
            isMouseDown = false
            if isDragging
                $test.trigger("x-stopDrag", evt)
                isDragging = false
            else
                $test.trigger("x-click", evt)
        .on "mousemove", (evt) ->
            console.log isMouseDown, isDragging
            if isMouseDown && not isDragging
                $test.trigger("x-startDrag", evt)
                isDragging = true
            if isDragging
                $test.trigger("x-drag", evt)
        .on "mouseleave", (evt) ->
            isMouseDown = false
            if isDragging
                isDragging = false
                $test.trigger("x-cancelDrag", evt)
        # handlers for custom events
        .on "x-startDrag", (x, evt) -> 
            console.log("started dragging")
            $draggedInterval = $("<div>", {
                class: "interval"
                css: 
                    left: evt.clientX
            }).appendTo($test)
        .on "x-stopDrag", (x, evt) -> 
            console.log("stopped dragging")
            $draggedInterval = undefined
        .on "x-cancelDrag", -> 
            console.log("canceled dragging")
            $draggedInterval.remove()
            $draggedInterval = undefined
        .on "x-click", (x, evt) -> 
            console.log("click")
        .on "x-drag", (x, evt) ->
            console.log("drag")
            $draggedInterval.css("width", evt.clientX - $draggedInterval.position().left)
```

Appears to work in Firefox and IE10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you need to use the `user-select` property and set it to `none`, so that the div can't be selected and behaves normally for mouse events (This is what is usually done for complex UI elements).

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select :

> **none**: None of the element's content can be selected. This is a **very
>   important** value of user-select **for user interface elements** in
>   particular. This value is one of the aspects of how a button behaves.
>   **The user cannot select any of the content inside the button**. If for
>   example, a user uses a pointing device to click on an element with
>   user-select: none, what happens when the pointing device button is
>   "down" is addressed by the user-input property, whereas when that
>   pointing device button is "released", this property ensures that no
>   selection of the contents of the element may remain. Another way to
>   explain this is that user-select: none is what gives a button its
>   "push-button-springy" feel. The value of 'none' is also useful for
>   static text labels in a user interface which are not meant to be
>   selected. For example, in the header of an email message window, the
>   portion that says "Name:" cannot be selected, whereas the content
>   following it can be. Such a static text label would also have
>   user-input: none.

I saw this error because of the **not-allowed** cursor: [image: not-allowed cursor]

Here's a the corrected JS-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r8Phv/7/

**User-select** is not yet implemented in browsers, but the vendor-prefixes work for Firefox2+, Chrome 6+, Opera 15, and IE 10.

Here are the support tables for user-select: http://caniuse.com/user-select-none